# Evenly Spread HTML which overflow from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement, where I want the overflow HTML of one `div` passed to another `div` displayed on same page.

Presently, I have created a JavaScript solution, which works very well with small HTML, but it hangs the browser in case of HTML exceeds one limit.

I want to know if there is any existing CSS solution or JavaScript API available for this purpose.

Any pointers will be helpful.

I found one Solution and tried using it, but its not supported across browser.

http://www.broken-links.com/2011/11/07/introducing-css-regions/

Comment: may be you should create some jsfiddle ?

Comment: You might be able to get away with floating content around a big div containing your text so that it looks like the text is flowing from one box to another... do you have a sample of what its supposed to look like? What you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: In the possible solution he mentioned there is reference to http://www.broken-links.com/2011/11/07/introducing-css-regions/. In chrome 15+ the text should be spread around those 3 boxes.

Comment: But then again. Im on chrome 27 and the text is not in those boxes..